# check all the input fields are empty or not in looped div (clicked)

Tags: javascript, autosave, focusout

I have looped input fields in a div and i want check all the input are filled or no and if filled want to save automatically. I tried with following code

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i <3; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="quick_row" id="row_<?php echo $i++; ?>" >
        <div class="span3"><input id="form_no" name="form_no" value="" class="inputbox required form_no" type="text"><span class="msg"></span></div>
        <div class="span3"><input id="name" name="name"  value="" class="inputbox required"  type="text"><span class="msg"></span></div>
        <div class="span3"><input id="nic" name="nic"  value="" class="inputbox required nic" maxlength="12" minlength="12" type="text"><span class="msg"></span></div>
        <div class="span3"><input id="mobile" name="mobile_no"  value="" class="inputbox required mobile" maxlength="10" type="text"><span class="msg"></span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<?php }  ?>
```

[image]

```
js(this).find(".quick_row input").on("focusout change", function(){

//js("#empower_quick input").on("focusout change", function(){
    var inputValidate = true;
   js(this).find(".quick_row input").each(function(index, element){           
        if (js(element).val() == "")
           inputValidate = false;
    });

    if (inputValidate){
//          alert("sdfsfdsf");
       // js("#form2").show();
    }      
         // alert("pramod");
});
```

Comment: Not solving your problem with this comment. BUT `id`s should be unique,  your HTML has not unique `id`s which is bad. There is either a reason to use unique `id`s or there is no reason to use them.

Comment: Can you provide a JsFiddle? That would be nice, thanks :)